# Error with trying to compile with make.(This also includes a snapshot after doing apt-get update)

Tags: 12.04, apt, compiling, make, asterisk

This is the error I get:

```
Fetched 120 kB in 1min  1s (1,937 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://update.yuuguu.com hardy Release: The following signatures                  couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 483881FD2506E8CC
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5EC48884BB901940
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease 

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://....archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '....archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/asterisk/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.0+2.6.0# apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your /etc/apt/sources.list is messed up. Those "...." before "archive.ubuntu.com" looks wrong.

Comment: Try running "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: I think all this may be just a connectivity problem. You might see if you can reach the archives in question with your web browser. I've seen this kind of error as a temporary thing that went away by itself, probably a temporary Internet reachability thing. I do notice that you have both hardy and precise archives listed. If you can reach the archives with your browser, try `sudo apt-get update` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You do not have public keys to some repositories. This means that your package manager considers these repositories to be insecure. This [website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) should help you retrieve the keys and update your apt database.
2. Your computer can not connect to one repository. There are many possible reasons to this. It might be due to wrong network settings on your machine, or the repository might be down, or...

Comment: John,i can access the repositories correctly,those dots are not in the sources.list Popey,and thats what i got haris on the top.

Comment: Wait,i found some errors and i fixed it. Thank you!